# Is parallel testing on java more efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, parallel-processing

I have been studying making Junit tests parallel, and I realized that when I run my test by making them parallel, their process times increase. Running tests synchronous takes approximately 3 seconds:

[image]

After I initialize  `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true`  on my  `junit-platform.properties`  file, it took nearly 6 seconds:

[image]

Can someone explain to me what is the deal with this?

Comment: Do your tests share any resources?

Comment: Yes some of them

Comment: There is usually overhead with any concurrency. Same with parallel streams. Concurrency isn't a silver bullet to make things faster. The benefit needs to exceed the cost. If your tests take 3 seconds, I don't see the point in trying to make them faster.

Comment: I am just trying to learn differences. In what kind of situations shall I use parallel testing.

Comment: It could be beneficial for small, algorithmic based test-cases with many input variations for example. If your testcases are heavy (more integration-like), starting a full spring-boot application for example, I dont think parellel tests would benefit you.

Theres no clear separation that could be described. It has to be decided on a case-to-case basis. That said, I never even tried to use parallel tests myself tbh.